# How do I find the min and max of a list?

Tags: ocaml

where `GEQ` represents "greater than or equal" and
`LT` represents "less than".
I need to make a function `listComparisons : int list -> comparison list` such that a call `(listComparisons [n_1; n_2; n_3; ...; n_k])` returns a list `[c_1; c_2; ...; c_k]`, where `c_1` is always `GEQ`, and for each `i, c_(i+1)` is `GEQ` if `n_i <= n_(i+1)`, and `LT` otherwise.

```
type comparison = GEQ | LT

let rec listComparisons intList = 
        match intList with 

        | [] -> []
        | x :: xs' ->
                match c_i with GEQ ? 
                let rec loop i =     
                        if c_(i+1) >= c_i     
                        then c_(i+1)=GEQ     
                        else c_(i+1)=LT;;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm going to suggest you read the [OCaml Programming Guidlines on indentation](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/guidelines.html#Indentation-of-programs).

Answer (score 1):

So, as I understand it, if we have a list:

```
[4; 6; 1; 8; 9; 2]
```

Then that would map to:

```
[GEQ; LT; GEQ; LT; LT; GEQ]
```

The following doesn't add that extra `GEQ` value onto the front of the list, but does the comparisons you're looking for.

```
let rec list_comparisons int_list =
  match int_list with
  | [] | [_] -> []
  | x::(x'::_ as xs) when x < x' -> LT :: list_comparisons xs
  | x::(x'::_ as xs) -> GEQ :: list_comparisons xs
```

We pattern match on the input list. If it's either empty or has one element, we return an empty list. Otherwise we bind the first two elements in the list to `x` and `x'`, respectively. The tail of the list is bound to `xs`. When the first element is less than the second element, we get `LT` and the result of running `list_comparisons` on the tail. Otherwise, `GEQ`.

The important part is realizing the fundamentally recursive nature of lists, and using a matching recursive algorithm for handling them.

Now, this could be done tail-recursively, making it stack-friendly for large lists. It also provides an excellent opportunity to add that leading `GEQ`.

```
let list_comparisons int_list =
  let rec aux acc lst =
    match lst with
    | [] | [_] -> GEQ :: List.rev acc
    | x::(x'::_ as xs) when x < x' -> aux (LT :: acc) xs
    | x::(x'::_ as xs) -> aux (GEQ :: acc) xs
  in
  aux [] int_list
```